# How to use TypeScript union types in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to apply types to ReactJS props as implemented in the following interface. AS you can see the type `tags` is union type

```
export interface TagInterface {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

export interface PostInterface {
  tags: TagInterface[] | string[];
}
```

I have been able to to successfully use this type in a component inside a function as shown

```
 onClick={() => handleClick(post.tags[0] as string)}
```

Now when i try to implement this type on another component TypeScript is throwing an error

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string | TagInterface'.
  Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getPostData = async () => {
      const { data: posts }: DataInterface = await getRelatedPosts(
        post.tags[0].name // this produces an error
      );
      setRelatedPosts(posts.results);
    };
    getPostData();
  }, []);
```

How can I properly set the type from the union type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Property `name` is not common to `string` and `TagInterface`.
Thus, you need to have two code paths for two cases:

- `tag` is a `string`
- `tag` is a `TagInterface`

TS will try to analyze your code and give you access to most precise type it inferred. The process is called [Narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html), and in some cases it can be fully transparent, and in some cases you need to check what is the actual type of the object you are dealing with.

In case of `string | TagInterface` union, the most straightorward approach is a [typeof type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#typeof-type-guards).

```ts
interface TagInterface {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

function getName(tag: TagInterface | string) {
  if (typeof tag === 'string') {
    return tag;
  } else {
    return tag.name;
  }
}

console.log(getName('stringTag'));
console.log(getName({
  id: 1,
  name: 'tagInterfaceTag'
}));
```

Type assertion that you used in your onclick handler:
`post.tags[0] as string` is not a solution. With this assertion, you force TS to treat tag as a string - it will fail at runtime if it is not.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=5&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpwOYElzXk5AbwChllgATALmRAFcBbAI2gG5Ta4GIaBnMKKAzsAvsWIw6IBGGAB7EMgwQwAOS4QAFGEw102XLEQoAPsn6CQGAJREOwGMm0BPAA4Q5jnRmQBef8gA5BZCgbYkZGRQKnRQit7sZCLIEAA2vCgRkdFgsfGYAHQgGonIYmLECAq8cqkQBalyGJrKahqawQJC%20mHW7FUgNXUNTS0q6tyaWZQ0AIwANBzF3DSB3jiQRkg9xCLWfUA)

Comment: You can overload your function and narrow return type. [Example](https://tsplay.dev/wR55QW)

Comment: I am new to react typescript and i was really struggling how to implement a typeguard. This helped alot. Thanks

Comment: @Muteshi While not applicable to your original question, take a look at discriminated unions - you're likely to see them a lot.